# HashMap in Collection Framework

Tags: java

```
class A{
private static Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
public A()
{
    map.put("micky","hello");
    map.put("micky","hey");
}
public int size()
{
     return map.size();
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     System.out.println(map.size());
}
```

// Why is it giving 0 as a answer. could anyone explain me?
}

Comment: What do you think, why it should _not_ be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding elements in Constructor to the map. But you never called the constructor. That's the reason.

When you instatiate Class A, that invokes the constructor and you can see the change in size.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     A a = new A(); //invokes constructor.
     System.out.println(map.size()); // now prints size
}
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That's another story. Main is in the same class as of now.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding elements in constructor of class A to the map HashMap.

You never call the constructor so the size of your map HashMap is 0, as it must be because map has 0 elements.

It's quite strange what you're doing there but if you want to have 2 items in hashmap you must instantiate an element of class A.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     // METHOD 1
     var smth = new A();
     System.out.println(map.size()); // You will see the difference

     // METHOD 2 
     System.out.println(new A().size()); //call constructor, add items, call the size method of class A
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to call the constructor of the class for adding any value to the map before of print the content

Answer (score 0):

You must access the size() method through classA refrence:

Like

**System.out.println(A.map.size());**

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the default constructor, so HashMap is also not initialized. Try the below code, it is working correctly

```
import java.util.*;
class A
{
    private static Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    public A()
    {
        map.put("micky","hello");
            map.put("micky","hey");
    }
    public int size()
    {
            return map.size();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(map.size());
    }
}
```